# Jbehave Thucydides Test Case getting skipped

Tags: bdd, jbehave, thucydides

Hello i am new to jbehave and thucydides and the issue i am facing is  all the steps are executed in the .java file but it only skips the @when step due to which my test gets skipped. I tried several options but it always marks when as pending when i run the test.

Answer (score 0):

After executing tests case, check your console or report file for story/step error annotation.
Tests that contain no steps are considered to be pending. If one of steps (the "given-when-then" structure) gets PENDING while executing, then whole test gets labelled as SKIPPED. http://www.wakaleo.com/thucydides-one-page/thucydides.html#_defining_high_level_tests_in_junit - 6.2.1

From my experience, most pending steps ("given-when-then") are from bad spelling of a step name/title. Step from .story file and implementation file of a story (your_story.java depending on language) are different. Like "xx yy" =/= "xx yv"